# Which memory has the access time as fast as the processor speed?

Tags: memory, cpu

Usually,the processor has to wait for the memory, recently I came across a question which stated something like,

> How will you construct a state-zero machine?

Which memory should I use? I stated Cache.

Comment: Why a -1? I don't find a reason behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to use [SRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random_access_memory), whose access speed reaches into the single-digit nanoseconds.

Comment: The SRAM waits for the next clock cycle,slowing its speed.I guess that won't work

Comment: @Fahad -- erm, doesn't that mean that it's *faster* than CPUs?

Comment: @RCIX:According to what I know,DRAM responds as fast as it can to the change in control input,while SRAM waits for the next clock cycle to respond.Doesn't that mean that DRAM responds faster?

Comment: @fahad: "As fast as it can" may mean multiple cycles (and it usually does).

Comment: @Ignacio:Multiple cycles?

Comment: @fahad: Yes. DRAM is *slow*, so the system clock ticks several times before it's able to respond. The exact number of ticks are what the latency values are about.

Answer (score 1):

> [Multi-level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) caches generally operate by checking the smallest Level 1 (L1) cache first; if it hits, the processor proceeds at high speed. If the smaller cache misses, the next larger cache (L2) is checked, and so on, before external memory is checked.

Therefore I would recommed you a CPU with large L1 & L2 cache.

Answer (score 0):

You actually wouldn't use cache or SRAM.  You'd confine your machine to using registers only, which are literally on the CPU itself.  This is the basis of RISC vs. CISC computing.

Comment: I think that the instructions are out of the size range of registers

Comment: Well don't forget on a RISC or 64-bit CPU you do have a lot of them, compared with a 32-bit CPU.